# Unexpected performance of the concurrent.futures in Python

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import torch.optim as optim
import time


def init_params(model, init_policy, init_seed):
    torch.manual_seed(init_seed)
    for module in model.modules():
        if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(module.weight)
            if module.bias is not None:
                nn.init.normal_(module.bias)

class OneLayerNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_size, classes_size):
      super(OneLayerNNModel, self).__init__()
      self.linear = nn.Linear(feature_size, classes_size)
    def forward(self, x):
      x = self.linear(x)
      return x
    
def get_model_param_df(model):
    w = torch.cat([p.data.flatten() for p in model.parameters()])
    df = pd.DataFrame(w.cpu().detach().numpy())
    return df
    

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import concurrent.futures


##data##
iris = load_iris()
iris.keys()
x = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
test_size=0.2

fixed_data = True
fixed_init = False
n_exp = 50

data_seeds_list = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1).tolist()*n_exp if fixed_data else np.random.randint(1, 1000, n_exp)
param_seeds_list = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1).tolist()*n_exp if fixed_init else np.random.randint(1, 1000, n_exp)


##optimization##
steps = 1000
init_policy = 'xaviern'
lr = 1e-2
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
verbose = False
feature_size = 4 # or x_train.shape[1]
class_size = 3



def experiment(x, y, param_seed, data_seed, test_size, steps,
            feature_size, class_size, init_policy, lr, verbose=True, log_scale=10):

       
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, 
                                                        test_size=test_size, random_state=data_seed)

    pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler())

    # get mean and std
    pipe_scaled = pipe.fit(x_train)
    x_train_scaled = pipe_scaled.transform(x_train)

    model = OneLayerNNModel(feature_size, class_size).double()
    init_params(model, init_policy, param_seed)

    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

    log_freq = steps // log_scale if steps > log_scale else 1
    
    mini_batch_size = x_train.shape[0]

    results = {}

    for step in range(steps):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        shuffled_idx = torch.randperm(x_train_scaled.shape[0])

        x_mini_b = torch.from_numpy(x_train_scaled[shuffled_idx, :][:mini_batch_size])
        y_mini_b = torch.from_numpy(y_train[list(shuffled_idx)[:mini_batch_size]])

        output = model(x_mini_b)
        loss = criterion(output, y_mini_b)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        p_hat = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
        target_hat = torch.argmax(p_hat, dim=1)
        acc = 100 * target_hat.eq(y_mini_b).sum() / y_mini_b.numel()

        if step % log_freq == 0 and verbose:
            print(f'step: {step}: loss: {round(loss.item(), 2)}, acc {round(acc.item(), 2)}.')

    w = model.linear.weight.data.cpu().detach().numpy()
    b = model.linear.bias.data.view(-1, 1).cpu().detach().numpy()
    theta  = np.concatenate((w, b), axis=1)

    results['data_seed'] = data_seed
    results['param_seed'] = param_seed
    results['theta'] = theta
    results['loss_train'] = loss.item()
    results['acc_train'] = acc.item()
    results['lr'] = lr
    results['steps'] = steps
    results['init_policy'] = init_policy

    acc_test, loss_test = test(pipe_scaled, x_test, y_test, model, verbose)

    results['loss_test'] = loss_test.item()
    results['acc_test'] = acc_test.item()
    
    return results


def test(pipe_scaled, x_test, y_test, model, verbose=True):
    x_test_scaled = torch.from_numpy(pipe_scaled.transform(x_test))
    output = model(x_test_scaled)
    p_hat = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)

    y_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(y_test)

    target_hat = torch.argmax(p_hat, dim=1)
    acc = 100 * target_hat.eq(y_test_torch).sum() / y_test_torch.numel()
    loss = criterion(output, y_test_torch)
    
    if verbose:
        print(f'Test loss: {round(loss.item(), 2)}, Test acc {round(acc.item(), 2)}%.')

    return acc, loss



results_list = []

proceess_lst = []

start =  time.time()

for param_seed, data_seed in zip(param_seeds_list, data_seeds_list):
        
    results = experiment(x, y, param_seed, data_seed, test_size, steps,
            feature_size, class_size, init_policy, lr, verbose)

print(f'No multi time :{time.time()-start}')

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

    for param_seed, data_seed in zip(param_seeds_list, data_seeds_list):
        
        process = executor.submit(experiment, *(x, y, param_seed, data_seed, test_size, steps,
                feature_size, class_size, init_policy, lr, verbose))
        proceess_lst.append(process)
        print('done')
        
    for process in concurrent.futures.as_completed(proceess_lst):
        result = process.result()
        print('complete')
        results_list.append(result)


df = pd.DataFrame(results_list)
print(df)
```

In this part of the code I did parallelization with `concurrent.futures`:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

     for param_seed, data_seed in zip(param_seeds_list, data_seeds_list):
        
         process = executor.submit(experiment, *(x, y, param_seed, data_seed, test_size, steps,
                 feature_size, class_size, init_policy, lr, verbose))
         proceess_lst.append(process)
         print('done')
        
     for process in concurrent.futures.as_completed(proceess_lst):
         result = process.result()
         results_list.append(result)
         print('complete')
```

I have a server with 56-cores of CPU. When I run this code on the server, it engages all of the cores and It takes 96 seconds to run. But when I run the code sequentially without any parallel processing it takes 59 seconds.

I expected to see it has 56 times better performance than I had on one core. But, It even took longer than sequential run.

What am I missing or what it is that I do wrong?

Comment: How do we reproduce your issue?

Comment: Data is pickled when sent between processes, this is obviously taking a significant amount of time.  You could try pickling and unpickling those parameter you're trying to pass to see how much time/space that takes

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html if you've not heard of pickling before

Comment: @nicomp I edited the post and put my entire code here.